# Transit in Turkey

Tags: transit, transit-visas, turkey

I’m going to US I got USA visa already. But I need to stop in Sabiha and change to Istanbul airport. Do I need transit visa? What is known traveler number?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: I hope you have lot's of transit time - because those two airports.... wowzers... are very _very_ far apart.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need transit visa?

Depends on your citizenship. Since you have to change airport you need proper documentation to enter Turkey

> What is known traveler number?

The US has programs for frequent travelers such as Global Entry or Nexus. These programs make immigration in the US a lot easier. You don't need one, though. If you are not participating in any of these programs, you can just leave the field blank